# Magento 2 : Event when customer in backend is created and updated

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer-account

I want to know how to solve this problem:

I need to trigger an observer when a customer is created and one different when customer is updated.

I was using `customer_save_before` event which works everytime you press Save Customer, the problem with this event is that I don't know if the user is created or updated. I have tried to get the ID of the customer and do something like this:

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

if($customer->getId() == null){

    $event = $CREATE_ACCOUNT_EVENT;
}
else {
    $event = $UPDATE_ACCOUNT_EVENT;
}
```

The problem is that it always sends event $UPDATE_ACCOUNT_EVENT; It's like if the ID is created always before accessing to the observer.
Is there any other event which just triggers when customer is created? so I can use that one for $CREATE_ACCOUNT_EVENT;

If not how can I check if the ID of the customer exists or not?

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `customer_register_success` event for create account event in your custom module.

Also, below is the reference link for all the events list available in Magento 2.

> https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/list-of-all-events-in-magento-2/

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: But is this event for admin panel? I have used this event just in frontend

Comment: You can give a try with this event in the admin, I'm not sure its working or not.

Comment: Wow I did not believe that it could work on backend, I just put my events.xml file inside admin html, seems to work.

Comment: it's not working for me, can you bit more clarify?

Comment: @VivekParmar you can get customer object with $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer(); in the observer and then you can use your own logic in the execute function.

Comment: @Sumit I am asking about particular event, I can use "adminhtml_customer_save_after" for create account from backend.

Comment: @VivekParmar Yes, you can use adminhtml_customer_save_after event for admin customer save and get customer object with same $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer() in your observer class.

Answer (score 0):

There is not specific event for customer update you can try with below  event

> adminhtml_customer_prepare_save